# minimum number of terms to choose from numbers $1$to $n$ such that sum of those terms is $X$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

We are given n numbers from 1 to n(inclusive).What is the minimum number of terms we need to choose such that sum of those terms is X.

Eg. If numbers are $1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$ and X is 7 ,then the answer is 2 because we can form $7$ by taking ($1$,$6$) or ($3$,$4$) or($2$,$5$) and all of these need just two terms instead of $3$ terms as(1+2+4).If x is$6$,ans is $1$and if x=$11$ ,ans is $2$.
Similarly for $1$,$2$,$3$,$4$ and x=$10$,ans is 4 as we need all four terms to have sum $10$.

Comment: With your example of $n=6$, you can get to $6$ with one, to $11$ with two, to $15$ with three, ..., to $21$ with six. Can you generalise this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume for this problem that we can use non repeated numbers to sum up to $x$. To solve this we need the formula to sum from $n$ to $n-k$. We want the closed form of

$$f(n,k)=\sum_{j=0}^{k}n-j=\sum_{j=0}^{k}n-\sum_{j=0}^{k}j=(k+1)n-(k+1)k\frac12=\\=nk-\frac{k^2}2-\frac{k}2+n=-\frac12 k^2+(n-\frac12)k+n,\quad\text{ for }k\le n$$

then we want to know

$$m=\min\{k:f(n,k)>x\}$$

We can simplify these calculations if we use a generalized version of $f(n,k)$ where $k$ is a real number instead of a natural number, then we evaluate

$$f(n,k_x)=x\\k_x=n-\frac12-\sqrt{n^2+\frac14+n-2x}$$

then $$m=\lceil k_x+1\rceil$$